# Error deploying database to SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, forms-authentication, azure-sql-database

I'm using forms authentication to handle users and attempting to deploy my database to SQL Azure, but getting this error message:

[image: azure error]

The only table of the four listed that I utilize is `aspnet_Membership`, and the only other table I use is `aspnet_Users` from implementing forms authentication. What is `TextInRowSize` and why does SQL Azure care about it? Do I have any option to modify `aspnet_Membership` to make it compatible?

If it would be easier to remove the current system altogether and replace it with my own, I'm fine with that too.

Comment: Which version of SQL Azure are you using?

Comment: I'm using whatever is on `windowsazure.com`. I don't see a SQL Azure version listed anywhere though. It does say `Latest SQL Database Update (V12)` on my SQL database server tab if that's useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by generating a SQL Azure script for the DB, and running it on Azure. Here's how I solved it:

First, open SQL Server, right click the database you want to transfer and click "Tasks > Generate Scripts..."

[image]

Next, click "Advanced" on the scripting options panel and find the row "Script for the database engine type." Select "Windows Azure SQL Database" and click OK (Note: if you have data that you want to transfer as well, choose "Schema and Data" from the "Types of data to script" option).

[image]

Proceed thru the rest of the script generation dialog, remembering where you saved the script file. Connect to your database server using SQL Server or windowsazure.com. Generate a new query for your new database, enter the script that was generated by SQL Server and execute.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an error in the data-tier application framework. I can suggest a workaround to get your database to Azure:
Use SqlPackage.exe (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) from the command line to extract a dacpac file with all table data. Then use SqlPackage.exe to deploy that dacpac file to your database in Azure. The extract command would look something like:

```
C:\>"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /a:extract /scs:"Data Source=yourSqlServer;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=yourDatabase" /tf:C:\temp\mydatabase.dacpac /p:ExtractAllTableData=true
```

And the import command would look something like:

```
C:\>"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /a:publish /tcs:"Data Source=yourAzureSQLServer.database.windows.net;User Id=yourUserId;Password=yourPassword;Initial Catalog=yourDatabase" /sf:C:\temp\mydatabase.dacpac
```

Comment: I'm always a little wary of _workarounds_ as they can end in defects. Do you have any experience with the longevity of this solution? I just feel like I'm getting the error for a reason. What would be the typical choice for deployment of an application using forms authentication if SQL Azure rejects it? I'm open to changing deployment environments altogether.

Answer (score 0):

So quick suggestions since I see you are using V12 which should support those properties now.

First make sure you are using SSMS 2014 SP1 at least, this has a number of fixes for using V12. Secondly make sure you install the May 2015 update to DacFX (which is the program that creates bacpac files) you can install it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46898

This should get you to the best possible chance of your import/export working.

Comment: I'm using SSMS 2012 Express. Must I upgrade or is there a way to make it work with 2012?

Comment: I highly suggest SSMS 2014 SP1. You can use the Express version though (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver2014express.aspx) It will make the overall experience better when managing a v12 SQL Azure database.

Comment: It appears Microsoft has removed the download for the 2014 SP1 because of customer issues. Upgrading to 2014 gave me a different error regarding `Table hint without WITH is not supported on SQL Azure` when validating `aspnet_Membership_GetNumberOfUsersOnline`. Looks like I'll have to wait for Microsoft to post that download for the service pack. I'll come back and accept if it works, thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like TextInRowSize stores large data for older SQL Server types such as text and ntext. You would need to change it's type to nvarchar(max).

Here's a link to a more detailed explanation.

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/unsupported-property-textinrowsize-set-and-is-not-supported-when-used-as-part-of-a-data-package